# Did someone have problems with metaboanalystR CrossReferencing error?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to run some tutorials of metaboanalystR and I have a problem with function CrossReferencing

```
mSet<-CrossReferencing(mSet, "name")
[1] "Reading data unsuccessful, attempting to re-download file..."
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  557k  100  557k    0     0   557k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  457k
[1] "Loading files from server unsuccessful. Ensure curl is downloaded on your computer."
Error in .read.metaboanalyst.lib("compound_db.rds") : 
  objeto 'my.lib' no encontrado
```

I have already install curl, but nothing happens.

Did anyone have the same error?

Thank you

Comment: Okay. I just get it. Once you run mSet<-CrossReferencing(mSet, "name") a rds will be download in your directory.
We just load compound_db.rds and we create a new data

my.lib<-compound_db.rds

and then we repeat the command line

mSet<-CrossReferencing(mSet, "name")